# Wicket dataprovider query / search time

Tags: search, datatable, wicket, timing, provider

I'm displaying (Lucene)search results in Wicket using a `DataTable`. The Datatable uses a IDataProvider to populate the toolbars and cells.

I try to figure out the amount of time it took to do the query. A typical query involves calls to

- `size(...)`
- `iterator(...)`
- `model(..)`

What would be a good approach to count the time spend in these methods? I can implement stuff like `System.currentTimeMillis()` in each of these calls, but what would be the 'proper' place to do this?

And also, I would like to display this time in a Toolbar, so somehow I should make sure when the 'dataloading' part is done. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If at all i would measure the time in the `iterator()` method. Unless you really have a big list and the time the `size()` is significant i would say this is enough. I dont see a way to give you the execution time measured in the `iterator()` method somewhere up.

I know that there is something like: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/devutils/inspector/RenderPerformanceListener.html but i've never used it.

You could also try to hook into the `RequestCycle`. There is a method `getStartTime()`
http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/RequestCycle.html#getStartTime(). You could end measuring in `onEndRequest()`.

There are also listeners for the RequestCycle. http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/IRequestCycleListener.html
There are `onBeginRequest` and `onEndRequest` methods. Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not actually measuring the DataProvider, but the Lucene method returning the results, I'd rather record the time in the method called by the dataprovider (assuming that there's something like a search service class).

As an advantage, other `DataProviders` calling the same method will be measured too, without touching them. Maybe there is an even more central place to put it? A single method through which every search request will have to pass?

Personally, I like `StopWatch` from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library, it is quite self-explaining to use. However if you do not already need the library otherwise, it would probably a bit oversized to add it just for time measurement. `currentTimeMillies` works fine as well.

Comment: The problem is that a request consists of at least three different calls, which are fired by wicket, and there is no guarantee on how and when they will be called. There is no onbeforedatagather and afterdatagather, which would fulfill my needs.